# Exit a script when user presses "Ok" in ui.alert prompt

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple function with an `if` statement inside and one of the conditions contain an ui.alert with some information and after that I want the script to stop executing.

```
function foo() {
  doingStuff();
  if (thisHappens) {
    ui.alert("script will exit");
  }
  doingMoreStuff();
}
```

How can I get the script to not execute `doingMoreStuff()`.

The behavior I'm after is the same as if the user presses the `x` in the top corner of the alert box.

Comment: Review program control flow statements and program logic in your preferred tutorial website and/or preferred JavaScript developer reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `thisHappens` is returned by the `doingStuff()`, as I wrote in the sample below, then you can simply add a `return` statement after displaying the alert.

```
function foo() {
  var value = doingStuff();
  if (value == exitCondition) {
    ui.alert("script will exit");
    return;
  }
  doingMoreStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `return;` to your if statement. `return;` will end the execution of your function. You can also use `return "Reason";` to give a reason for logging purposes. Or you can even replace the ui alert to `throw("Script has ended")` to show an alert to the user without a dialogue box.

My recommended script:

```
function foo() {
  doingStuff();
  if (thisHappens) {
    throw("Reason for script ending goes here");
  }
  doingMoreStuff();
}
```